# Change value of property "scrollTop" with JQuery

Tags: jquery

I try to give the "scrollHeight" value to "scrollTop" property with JQuery.

I found many articles on internet but the solutions don't work.

I'm here

```
$(".show").each(function() {

var test = $(this).prop('scrollHeight');
// test return a type 'number'
// test return value '2000'
$(this).scrollTop(test);

});
```

If I test with

```
 $(this).scrollTop(2000);
```

It works !

A link of my test with JSFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/Geo_x/fv8pfLap/2/

Comment: If `test` actually contains `2000` (the number), it's literally impossible for `scrollTop(test)` to behave differently from `scrollTop(2000)`. The problem is *elsewhere* in code you haven't shown (or because `this` is different), or what you've said about `test` isn't true.

Comment: What does your HTML look like? what are you trying to get from `scrollHeight`? The height of the element on the page, or viewport?

Comment: If I test with "console.log" in order $(this).prop('scrollTop') > var test > $(this).prop('scrollTop') I've : 1631 > 2084 > 1631

Comment: @Adjit I use this because when a new popup with list elements appear, the scroll is in the bottomand I want to have the scroll in the top

Comment: @Geo-x: That means the element you're referencing with `this` is already at its maximum `scrollTop` (and that `$(this).scrollTop(2084)` would have had no effect as well). You'll need to put a runnable [mcve] in the question using Stack Snippets (the `<>` toolbar button). Note: Make it runnable, something actually demonstrating the problem.